# Android Foreground Service() issue

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-service, foreground-service

The `mWindowManager` is throwing error in the `onDestroy` addressing `lateinit property mWindowManager has not been initialized`. But clearly it has been initialized inside `onStartCommand`.
I am starting this foreground service from an activity which is then destroyed. So this service run on its own. And when the user want to destroy the service he/she has to open the app and destroy it from the activity. This issue is only coming from some devices and i am confused what is causing this error. Can anyone help me with it?

```
class PremiumService : BaseService(), View.OnClickListener {

  private lateinit var mWindowManager: WindowManager

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params)

    return START_STICKY
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {

    mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView)
    super.onDestroy()
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that a service is started and immediately stopped? e.g. by a user double-tapping the start/stop button for it in the app. This might cause the service to never fully initialise, and not call onStartCommand(). You can test this by starting and stopping the service in succession with some test code.

Comment: I'll try that. Can you think of any other reason for it? The app is designed to work in the background i.e. no activity is alive except the service itself. Its basically a floating view (like the messenger bubble) & some people complain about it disappearing after some time.

Comment: I was contemplating if perhaps Android could be killing and restarting a service in some scenario, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why don't you initialize mWindowManager in assigment?

`private val mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager`

2. If you need to use lateinit var, you should check for initialization state:

`if (::mWindowManager.isInitialized) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView)`

3. Having any logic in `onDestroy()` for services is not recommended as you can't be sure it's called.
4. You don't need to remove views as they are removed automatically when the service is finished/killed.
5. I wrote [a few articles about floating windows on Android](https://localazy.com/blog/floating-windows-on-android-1-jetpack-compose-room#the-series). As the author of [Floating Apps](https://floatingapps.net), I know a bit about it and believe me, weird and absolutely unpredictable behavior is normal for some devices.

---

**Explanation of your problem:**

Your service may be, under some circumstances (not enough memory, etc.) restarted and as you don't want redelivery (you only have `START_STICK`), you `onStartCommand` is not called.

Comment: I know how to fix this issue but i was confused what was causing this bug. And also i guess the `START_STICKY ` is suppose to restart the service if it get destroyed, by calling the `onStartCommand`. I get a lot of complains that the floating view get disappeared in the middle of a tusk, even before this issue. Can you tell me what might be the reason for that? Anyway i am accepting your answer.

Comment: You are right, onStartCommand should be called but it's not always the case. Not sure why exactly - whether the service is started and stopped too fast due to some reason. With the redelivery, it works better. The service being killed without reason after some time, etc. is a bit problem and usually, it's necessary to disable battery optimization for the app and on some devices, there are another special options for retaining the service running. Be sure to check: dontkillmyapp.com